# Passing a variable with an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass a variable through the template into the directive. I've even got working examples in my own code, and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why this sample does not work.

I'm sure it's just a single character missing - an '@' or a '$' somewhere.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'baz';
}).
directive('myFnord',  
  function() {
    return{
     scope: {
      foo: '@'
     },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('!');
        console.log(scope.foo);
     }
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 600px; 
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div foo='foo' my-fnord>:)</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's `largeLoad.json`:

```
[{"name": "Moroni", "allowance": 505050505050505050,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Tiancum", "allowance": 53,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Jacob", "allowance": 27,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Nephi", "allowance": 29,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Enos", "allowance": 34,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Ether", "allowance": 42,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Alma", "allowance": 43,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Jared", "allowance": 21,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Moroni", "allowance": 50,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Tiancum", "allowance": 53,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Jacob", "allowance": 27,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Nephi", "allowance": 29,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Enos", "allowance": 34,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Ether", "allowance": 42,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Alma", "allowance": 43,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Jared", "allowance": 21,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Moroni", "allowance": 50,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Tiancum", "allowance": 53,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Jacob", "allowance": 27,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Nephi", "allowance": 29,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Enos", "allowance": 34,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Ether", "allowance": 42,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Alma", "allowance": 43,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Jared", "allowance": 21,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Moroni", "allowance": 50,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Tiancum", "allowance": 53,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Jacob", "allowance": 27,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Nephi", "allowance": 29,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Enos", "allowance": 34,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Ether", "allowance": 42,  "paid": false},
{"name": "Alma", "allowance": 43,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Jared", "allowance": 21,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Moroni", "allowance": 50,  "paid": true},
{"name": "Tiancum", "allowance": 53,  "paid": false}]
```

Comment: It should be `foo: '='`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What's the actual outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive, change

```
scope: {
  foo: '@'
},
```

to

```
scope: {
  foo: '='
},
```

Comment: I see. I was looking elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: If this answer worked for you please take the time to label it as correct, thanks!